# Find average and max time after grouping with linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given following class:

```
public class SessionData
{
    public Guid Session { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and made a list out of it:

```
public static List<SessionData> GetSessionData()
{
    Guid guid1 = Guid.NewGuid();
    Guid guid2 = Guid.NewGuid();

    List<SessionData> sessionData = new List<SessionData>
    {
        new SessionData {Session = guid1, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(3)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid1, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(2)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid2, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid2, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(4)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid1, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid1, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(25)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid2, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(20)},
        new SessionData {Session = guid1, Date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1)},
    };

    return sessionData;
}
```

I want to find the average duration of the sessions (1) and the longest session (2). Also how many sessions were there per day (3), week (4), month (5), year (6), total (7)?

I was trying to start from

```
var list = (from t in sessionData group t.Date by t.Session).ToList();
```

and try to find the duration (max Date - min Date) per session and continue from there. Is there a better way to directly do these calculations with Linq?

Comment: What you mean under _"average duration of the sessions "_? Like in numbers, what you have and what you expect to get?

Comment: How are session duration determined? You would need a start and end time

Comment: @Nkosi I asked the same question, but my guess is that each session has a starting point, and the end is when the next session in the list starts, but the list is not ordered...yet

Comment: Actually the Session guid determines the "Session" as is. From there on I would have to expand after a group by per Session guid and calculate the difference between the first and last date (after ordering of course) to find the duration of that particular "session". Basically this is an oversimplified amount of data of intensive logging of a multitenant chatbot orchestration platform and we would like to have a better insight on a dashboard for managers.

Comment: Do you have performance problems? Or is it the just how to do it problem?

Comment: How to write it. I know where to get but it's the inbetween part that gets me stuk at the moment. Performance might come later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sessionData = GetSessionData();

var longestSession = sessionData
    .GroupBy(sd => sd.Session)
    .Select(group => new Tuple<Guid, TimeSpan>(group.First().Session, group.Max(sd => sd.Date) - group.Min(sd => sd.Date)))
    .OrderBy(tuple => tuple.Item2)
    .Last()
    .Item1;

var averageDuration = sessionData
    .GroupBy(sd => sd.Session)
    .Select(group => new Tuple<Guid, TimeSpan>(group.First().Session, group.Max(sd => sd.Date) - group.Min(sd => sd.Date)))
    .Average(tuple => tuple.Item2.Minutes);
```

For you other questions I have no immediate LINQ solution, I will update as soon as I have an idea.

Comment: Seems to work for these already. Is it also possible to write these in a `from s in sessionData group by ...` way?

Comment: I'm sorry, but cannot help you with the query expression syntax... And there are some limitations to query expressions as well, so I'm not sure it's possible to use these...

Comment: Marking this as the answer as it already gave me the first indication on how to take an alternative way to my goal.